# How to search on multiple columns at same time using GreenDao?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, greendao

suppose I have two columns **Name** and **Surname**. There is one row with **Greame** in Name column and **Latham** in Surname. I want that row to be fetched when query key is **Greame Latham**.

How to achieve that using Greendao QueryBuilder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you to fetch data on the basis of two params:

```
if(childDao().queryBuilder()
             .where(ChildeDao.Properties.Name.like("%" + f_name+ "%"), 
                    ChildDao.Properties.Surname.like("%" +l_name+ "%"))
             .list().size() == 0){
//fetch from db
}
```

Comment: but it would not work when searched for `Grea` right? I mean for partial search?

Comment: this works for separate words. like for `Greame` and `Latham`. but not with one whole word `Greame Latham`